# Mule 4: Transforming SQL XML object to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, xml, dataweave, mulesoft

I am getting SQLXML resultset as an output of MS SQL stored procedure called from the Database Execute Stored Procedure shape.

The SQLXML resultset looks like:

```
<xmlcontent>
   <field1>val1</field1>
   <field2>val2</field2>
   <field3>val3</filed3>
</xmlcontent>
<xmlcontent>
   <field1>val1</field1>
   <field2>val2</field2>
   <field3>val3</filed3>
</xmlcontent>
<xmlcontent>
   <field1>val1</field1>
   <field2>val2</field2>
   <field3>val3</filed3>
</xmlcontent>
```

However, the payload is a bit weird, as it contains the XML output of length 2033 and then repeated as the array element until the payload is exhausted. The transform shape output with the just payload shows:

```
{
  "resultSet1": [
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "<xmlcontent><field1/><field2/><field3/>" --this content is of size 2033 max
    },
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "</xmlcontent><xmlcontent><field1/><fiel" --this content is of size 2033 max
    },
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "d2/><field3/><xmlcontent>"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am thinking of using another transform shape to append the values of "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" from the resultset1 array and then transforming to JSON. Is there a way in data weave to simplify this approach to get final JSON output as below?

```
    [
   {
      "field1": "val1",
      "field2": "val2",
      "field3": "val3"
   },
   {
      "field1": "val1",
      "field2": "val2",
      "field3": "val3"
   },
   {
      "field1": "val1",
      "field2": "val2",
      "field3": "val3"
   }
]
```

Comment: Where "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" comes from?

Comment: The input is not valid XML. It doesn't has a single root element. Any correct XML parser will reject it.

Comment: I think I got it. The input should be treated as text, not as an XML, right?

Comment: "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" comes from the output of Transform shape which takes input from the Database stored procedure shape. Luckily it doesn't change with every deployment. You are right, the XML we get as a SQL output is not a valid XML as it doesn't have a root node. But if we get values of all '"XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" nodes, we can use it to form a valid XML.

Comment: I added an answer with a fixed id. If you need it to come from somewhere else please add an explanation of the source to the question.

Comment: I guess you looked at the two code samples in the question but there was more to it in the explanation. Anyway, I have added the final expected output to the question now. I have got the values of all "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" nodes in the form of string, and manipulated it further to look like a valid XML. However, still have issues converting it to the expected JSON format. I was looking to simplify this approach of extracting all node values to string, converting it to XML and then transform it to JSON.

Comment: It is not clear what is the output of the database query and what the input for the question. Could you please indicate what is the actual input and expected output for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
{
  "resultSet1": [
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "<xmlcontent><field1>val1</field1><field2>val2</field2><field3>val3</field3>" 
    },
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "</xmlcontent><xmlcontent><field1>val1</field1><fiel" 
    },
    {
      "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "d2>val2</field2><field3>val3</field3></xmlcontent>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var id='XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B'
var body=payload.resultSet1 map (
    $[id]) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> accumulator ++ item)

---
read('<root>' ++ body ++ '</root>', "application/xml").root.*xmlcontent
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "val3"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "val3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the desired output with slight modification. I got the XML string and mapped it to the JSON format, some fields from XML had to be skipped in the mapping.